# Problema al cambiar el color del boton o forma

Tags: android-studio, xml, botón

Estoy intentando crear un **botón** redondo, al igual que intento cambiarle el color al botón pero no me realiza ningún cambio.

Supuse que seria algo por que cambie el estilo por el de **Material Design**
Al regresar a como estaba antes suceden 2 cosas

1. Se visualiza lo que quiero del botón
2. Se pierde el estilo de mis botones con **Material design**

Mi archivo de Styles esta de la siguiente manera.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDarkColor</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

tengo 2 tipos de botones

1. Button con Material design
2. Button simple

1.

```
<android.support.design.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/material_button"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:onClick="onClickButton"
            android:text="@string/iniciarSesion"
            />
```

2.

```
<Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_redondo"/>
```

mi archivo button_redondo es el siguiente

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">
<size
    android:width="50dp"
    android:height="50dp" />
<corners android:radius="25dp" />
<solid android:color="#e1ff4000" />
```

Comment: Tu archivo de styles esta sobrescribiendo el tema o comportamiento de Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar si tus botones de material design estan utilizando este tema va a modificar el comportamiento por defecto, prueba modificando otro tema que no sea MaterialComponents y se lo asignas al botón

Comment: Ok.. creo que lo entiendo.. lamentablemente no tengo muchos conocimiento, por lo tanto lo intente pero no funciono.. realizare un poco mas de investigación para poder realizar lo que sugieres.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes intentar con un `layer-list`, intenta modificar tu archivo `button_redondo` con el siguiente código:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval" >
        <size android:width="50dp"
              android:height="50dp" />
        <corners android:radius="25dp" />
        <solid android:color="#e1ff4000" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: modifique el archivo pero parece no funcionar.. no marca error ni nada pero sigue mostrando el botón de forma predeterminada.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto, agregué una captura de cómo se comporta con el

```
parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar"
```

[image: captura del comportamiento]

Mi drawable esta así:

```
<shape>
    <gradient android:startColor="#1f5208"
        android:endColor="#49ce0c"
        android:angle="270">
    </gradient>
    <corners android:radius="80dp"/>
</shape>
```

Y el layout así:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:background="@drawable/boton"
    android:text="Button1"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
    android:text="Button2"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    app:backgroundTint="@null"
    android:background="@drawable/boton"
    android:text="Button3"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:text="Button4"/>
```

Resumiendo: creo que el "boton 3" sirve, ya que MaterialComponents no hace caso al background, pero al corners sí hace caso.